# Unit testing angular service, Injecting dependencies through beforeeach doesn't get executed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine, viewchild

I am trying to unit test a component that has a @viewChild component and few more services.

Following is my spec.ts file.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UpStoryComponent,ExperienceListComponent, MdToHtmlPipe, SafeUrlPipe, FormatUrlPipe, CurrencyFormatPipe, NoCommaPipe, MoneyPipe, SafeHtmlPipe],
      imports: [ FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {'params': Observable.from([{ 'id': 1}])}, ContentfulService, MatchingFlowService, FormDataService, LocalStorageService, ScrollService, Title, UpnorwayLoaderService, MoneyService, DayCalculatorService],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]    
    }).compileComponents();
  });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpStoryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;     
    component.experienceListComponent = TestBed.createComponent(ExperienceListComponent).componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    contentfulService = TestBed.get(ContentfulService);
    spyOn(contentfulService, 'getEntryBySlug').and.callFake(function (args) {
      return of(blogPost);
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create', () => { 
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

The last beforeeach statement gets executed, but does not inject service as expected. If I place the last beforeeach statement as the second beforeeach, then the current second beforeeach doesn't get executed as expected.

There is no dependency between `ExperienceListComponent` and `ContentfulService`. But when injecting these two services through beforeach statements, only the first inject works, not the other.

What could be the reason for this? Appreciate if you could provide a solution for this.

Comment: When you say `does not inject service as expected` , what error are you getting

Comment: @ShashankVivek, the spied function within the service doesn't get executed.